# Upgrading my laptop from Sandy to Ivy bridge?

Tags: cpu, toshiba-laptop, intel-core-i5, intel-core-i3

my laptop gaming performance sucks, because I have an i3 with only 2 cores clocked on 2.2GHz (i3-2328M). So recently I found an i5 with also dual core but clocked on 2.5GHz with turbo up to 3.1GHz (i5-3210M). I have checked and compared parameters of those two, TDP = same, socket = same, but the bridges are different. After some search I found few answears, that say the ivy cpu can be put on a sandy motherboard laptop, but I need to be sure about my bios support. The problem is that my laptop (Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q) doesn't have it's motherboard name published so I can't know the support of motherboard. So if there is someone who knows more, will the mentioned i5 work with my H2O BIOS (Latest version from Toshiba - 6.80). Anyhow... Please, tell me, since the CPU is now very cheap but not for long and shipping is for me very expensive, so I don't want to invest a lot of money to discover that it doesn't work. Please do not move my question off, I really need help :(

Comment: There is no such thing as a "motherboard name" for a laptop. Pretty much every laptop has a unique motherboard designed just for that model/series. (So the laptop model *is* the motherboard model.) If the laptop was manufactured before the BIOS that supports Ivy Bridge was released then there is little chance that the CPU upgrade will work. Most importantly, the CPUs on laptops are soldered, which makes it nearly impossible to replace the CPU without special tools and expertise.

Comment: @Romen the sockets are FCPGA988 (non-soldered), so that is not a problem, about the bios. I don't really know. Toshiba basicaly shares minimal amount info of bios. I couldn't even find compatible CPUs.

Comment: It's nice to see a socketed mobile CPU! Did you also consider the physical dimensions of the new CPU? You might need thermal pads or have to delid it to make it fit in the existing heat sink if the thickness is different. Also, read the patch notes for your laptop BIOS updates, it will probably mention Ivy Bridge support if it was ever added.

Comment: Gosh. I found some nice info. I found a laptop from the same series (c850) with the i5-3210m and seems like all the C850s have the H000052750 motherboard (found this info by looking around). Is it possible that my laptop will cooperate with that i5 too? @Romen

Comment: that depends on the factors that you and I have both discussed already. A) Does it *physically fit* in the laptop? (Not just with the socket but the heat-sink too) B) Is your BIOS a new enough version?

Comment: @Arty If your laptop can use the same Bios as the c850 and you're not dealing with a BGA chip and the new chips fits in the available space it should work in that case. Best update the bios BEFORE changing the CPU. The laptop may not boot at all if you do it the other way around.

Comment: @Tonny, Now that we have enough information to say it *might* work, I think your comment should be added as an answer.

Comment: So I have searched BIOS updates supposed for the c850 series (which my laptop belongs to) and I foun some probally a registry update in change log, where ivy bridge has been mention and something with screen. That probally means that the ivy bridge comlatibility is not a problem anymore. Since you have thrown even more factors that may couse my laptop not support the cpu, I'll check it. But everything seems very fine to me!

Comment: I'll keep this unansweared till tomorrow, if anyone would like to post his comments that might help, because tomorrow I'm actually about to order the cpu. So. K7AAY, Romen and Tonny, big thanks to you for your help. It didn't take maybe even 2 hours and I've checked a lot of things that did one by one confirm the compatibility. Ofc, there are still few things left, but still. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you found your [i3-2328M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/70927/intel-core-i3-2328m-processor-3m-cache-2-20-ghz.html) CPU was socketed, and not a [Ball Grid Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) CPU factory-soldered to the laptop motherboard.

However, the chipset which shipped on that motherboard is factory-soldered, and not removable. It is not clear from the documentation available that changing the CPU to an [i5-3210M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/67355/intel-core-i5-3210m-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz-rpga.html) would result in a bootable PC, because of the difference in chipsets.

Also, the CPU is just one component among many; the other parts would still be the same, so the increase in speed would be small.

I would instead suggest saving for a less old used machine with faster  components.

Comment: Although, [there is a version of this chip that uses a rPGA988B socket](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i3/i3-2328m).

Comment: Soldering BGA is a highly specialized skill. Even those few that have mastered it are extremely loath to tackle a high pin-count package like a CPU. For an amateur it is completely impossible. So best make absolutely sure that that CPU is NOT a BGA version.

Comment: @K7AAY I have already dissasembled my laptop and I saw that the socket has that thing u rotate with screwdriver to put the cpu out, and the cpu i want to buy. Seller has sent me pics, it doesnt seem to be a BGA. Since even on the main cpu site of the i5 3210m is listed only the FCPGA988, and i think there is no soldered type of fcpga988

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for checking that!